# Kibana - process not starting- log not clear

Tags: kibana

Running on `Ubuntu 16.4`

Elastic version: `6.2.4`

Kibana version: `6.2.4`

Elastic is up and running on port `9200`.

Kibana suddenly stopped working, I am trying to run the start command: `sudo systemctl start kibana.service` and I get the following error in the service stdout(`journalctl -fu kibana.service`):

```
Started Kibana.
Aug 27 12:54:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 27 12:54:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 27 12:54:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 27 12:54:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 27 12:54:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
```

No details on this log.

My `yaml` configuration has only this props:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

I also have tried writing to a log file(hoping for more info there), I tried adding this configurations:

```
logging.dest:  /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
logging.verbose: true
```

I gave the folder/file full access control but nothing is being written there(still writing to the stdout)